# Flutter : json.Decode error using Provider

Tags: flutter, dart

I want saving **MobileVersionList** and **AppInfoList** data from API into SharedPreferences using this code :

## Global Provider

```
  //! Save AppInfoList To SharedPreferences
  String _encodeAppInfoList = '';
  String get encodeAppInfoList => _encodeAppInfoList;
  List get decodeAppInfoList => json.decode(_encodeAppInfoList) ?? [];
  List<AppInfoModel> get appInfoList =>
      decodeAppInfoList.map((json) => AppInfoModel.fromJson(json)).toList() ??
      [];

  Future<bool> setEncodeAppInfoList(String encodeAppInfoList) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result =
        await preferences.setString(_APP_INFO_LIST, encodeAppInfoList);
    await getEncodeAppInfoList();
    print("result setEncodeAppInfoList : $result");

    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }

  Future<String> getEncodeAppInfoList() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result = preferences.getString(_APP_INFO_LIST);
    _encodeAppInfoList = result;
    notifyListeners();
    print("result getEncodeAppInfoList : $result");
    return result;
  }

  //! Save Mobile Version From Database To SharedPreferences
  String _encodeMobileVersionList = '';
  String get encodeMobileVersionList => _encodeMobileVersionList;
  List get decodeMobileVersionList =>
      json.decode(encodeMobileVersionList) ?? [];
  List<MobileVersionModel> get mobileVersionList =>
      decodeMobileVersionList
          .map((json) => MobileVersionModel.fromJson(json))
          .toList() ??
      [];

  Future<bool> setEncodeMobileVersionList(String encodeAppInfoList) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result =
        await preferences.setString(_MOBILE_VERSION_LIST, encodeAppInfoList);
    await getEncodeMobileVersionList();
    print("result setEncodeMobileVersionList : $result");

    notifyListeners();
    return result;
  }

  Future<String> getEncodeMobileVersionList() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final result = preferences.getString(_MOBILE_VERSION_LIST);
    _encodeMobileVersionList = result;
    notifyListeners();
    print("result getEncodeMobileVersionList : $result");
    return result;
  }
```

## Mobile API

```
Future<String> getNewestMobileVersion() async {
    try {
      final response = await http
          .get('$_baseUrl/getNewestVersion')
          .timeout(Duration(seconds: 60));
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List mobileVersionList = responseJson["data"];
        String encodeMobileVersionList = jsonEncode(mobileVersionList);
        return encodeMobileVersionList;
      } else {
        throw CustomError(responseJson['message']);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

## AppInfo API

```
Future<String> getLogoClient() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get("$_baseUrl/getLogoClient").timeout(
            const Duration(seconds: 60),
          );
      final Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      if (responseJson["status"] == "ok") {
        List image = responseJson["data"];
        String encodeAppInfoList = jsonEncode(image);

        return encodeAppInfoList;
      } else {
        throw CustomError(responseJson["message"]);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return Future.error(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

> Everything it's ok, I can see the result saving data into sharedpreferences is success :

```
I/flutter ( 3897): result getEncodeMobileVersionList : [{"id":"3","version":"1.0.2","release":"0000-00-00","status":"0","change_log":"","target":"","created_by":"0","created_at":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updated_by":null,"updated_at":null}]
I/flutter ( 3897): result getEncodeAppInfoList : [{"kodeInfo":"1","namaInfo":"Integrasi Operasional Outlet","keteranganInfo":"Burger Klenger ERPOS Version 1.2","fileInfo":"img-1.png","logoInfo":"logo-1.png","loginBackgroundInfo":"bfront-1.png","loginLeftInfo":"bleft-1.png","loginSupportInfo":"bsupport-1.png","createBy":"","createTime":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","updateBy":"hambaallah","updateTime":"2020-02-09 06:32:57"}]
```

> But the problem is , Every I load My SplashScreen (I saving those in SplashScreen) , I get  error :

## Error

```
I/flutter ( 3897): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3897): The following FormatException was thrown building SplashScreen(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter ( 3897): [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#5b1c0], _InheritedTheme,
I/flutter ( 3897): _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<GlobalProvider>], state: _SplashScreenState#a043f):
I/flutter ( 3897): Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 3897):
I/flutter ( 3897): ^
I/flutter ( 3897):
I/flutter ( 3897): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 3897):   SplashScreen 
lib\main.dart:55
I/flutter ( 3897):
I/flutter ( 3897): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 3897): #0      _ChunkedJsonParser.fail  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:1394:5)
I/flutter ( 3897): #1      _ChunkedJsonParser.close  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:512:7)
I/flutter ( 3897): #2      _parseJson  (dart:convert-patch/convert_patch.dart:32:10)
I/flutter ( 3897): #3      JsonDecoder.convert  (dart:convert/json.dart:495:36)
I/flutter ( 3897): #4      JsonCodec.decode  (dart:convert/json.dart:153:41)
I/flutter ( 3897): #5      GlobalProvider.decodeMobileVersionList 
package:global_template/providers/global_provider.dart:229
I/flutter ( 3897): #6      GlobalProvider.mobileVersionList 
package:global_template/providers/global_provider.dart:231
I/flutter ( 3897): #7      _SplashScreenState.build 
package:klenger_burger_app/screens/splash_screen.dart:52
I/flutter ( 3897): #8      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4590
I/flutter ( 3897): #9      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4478
I/flutter ( 3897): #10     StatefulElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4646
I/flutter ( 3897): #11     Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4202
I/flutter ( 3897): #12     ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4461
I/flutter ( 3897): #13     StatefulElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4637
I/flutter ( 3897): #14     ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4456
I/flutter ( 3897): ...     Normal element mounting (115 frames)
I/flutter ( 3897): #129    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3430
I/flutter ( 3897): #130    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:5857
I/flutter ( 3897): ...     Normal element mounting (253 frames)
I/flutter ( 3897): #383    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3430
I/flutter ( 3897): #384    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3198
I/flutter ( 3897): #385    ComponentElement.performRebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4498
I/flutter ( 3897): #386    _InheritedProviderScopeMixin.performRebuild 

package:provider/src/inherited_provider.dart:220
I/flutter ( 3897): #387    Element.rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4202
I/flutter ( 3897): #388    ComponentElement._firstBuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4461
I/flutter ( 3897): #389    ComponentElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4456
I/flutter ( 3897): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
I/flutter ( 3897): #396    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount 
package:nested/nested.dart:223
I/flutter ( 3897): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
I/flutter ( 3897): #403    _NestedHookElement.mount 
package:nested/nested.dart:188
I/flutter ( 3897): ...     Normal element mounting (7 frames)
I/flutter ( 3897): #410    SingleChildWidgetElementMixin.mount 
package:nested/nested.dart:223
I/flutter ( 3897): #411    Element.inflateWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3430
I/flutter ( 3897): #412    Element.updateChild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:3198
I/flutter ( 3897): #413    RenderObjectToWidgetElement._rebuild 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1142
I/flutter ( 3897): #414    RenderObjectToWidgetElement.mount 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1113
I/flutter ( 3897): #415    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1055
I/flutter ( 3897): #416    BuildOwner.buildScope 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:2591
I/flutter ( 3897): #417    RenderObjectToWidgetAdapter.attachToRenderTree 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:1054
I/flutter ( 3897): #418    WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:935
I/flutter ( 3897): #419    WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/widgets/binding.dart:917
I/flutter ( 3897): (elided 11 frames from class _RawReceivePortImpl, class _Timer, dart:async, and dart:async-patch)
I/flutter ( 3897):
I/flutter ( 3897): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

## SplashScreen

```
class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    if (mounted) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        fetchAppInfo();
        fetchMobileVersion();
      });
    }
    return null;
  }

  fetchAppInfo() async {
    final globalProvider = Provider.of<GlobalProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final result = await appInfoApi.getLogoClient();
    await globalProvider.setEncodeAppInfoList(result);
  }

  void fetchMobileVersion() async {
    final globalProvider = Provider.of<GlobalProvider>(context, listen: false);
    final result = await mobileVersionApi.getNewestMobileVersion();
    await globalProvider.setEncodeMobileVersionList(result);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final globalProvider = Provider.of<GlobalProvider>(context);
    // final appInfoList = globalProvider.appInfoList;
    // final mobileVersionList = globalProvider.mobileVersionList;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      body: (globalProvider.encodeMobileVersionList == null ||
              globalProvider.encodeAppInfoList == null)
          ? LoadingFutureBuilder()
          : (globalProvider.mobileVersionList[0].version !=
                  globalProvider.versionPackageInfo)
              ? Center(
                  child: AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Newest APK Available'),
                    content: Text('Changelog \n 1.Fixed Bug'),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(onPressed: () => "", child: Text('Copy Link')),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () => "",
                          child: Text('Download Newest APK'))
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              : SplashScreenTemplate(
                  image: SplashScreenImage(
                      imageUrl:
                          "${appInfoApi.baseImageUrl}/${globalProvider.appInfoList[0].fileInfo}"),
                  navigateAfterSplashScreen:
                      (globalProvider.encodeUserList == null)
                          ? LoginScreen()
                          : WelcomeScreen(),
                ),
    );
  }
```

I thought this was because me directly calling the Provider , But the **json.decode** not yet finish in initState.

Can you Help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not make your splash screen background heavier.

`I/flutter ( 3897): _DefaultInheritedProviderScope<GlobalProvider>], state: _SplashScreenState#a043f):
I/flutter ( 3897): Unexpected end of input (at character 1)
I/flutter ( 3897):
I/flutter ( 3897): ^
I/flutter ( 3897):
I/flutter ( 3897): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 3897):   SplashScreen 
lib\main.dart:55`

From you above error log, it is clearing saying some Unexpected end of input is causing this issue and one widget was also involved. Try debugging once, it will show you the rootcause. Try to add the breakpoints at init state and at the body inside scaffold. Once you try this, please let me know. Happy to help & Happy coding.

Comment: I get crash at body breakpoint . What should i do next ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmB7p.png https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G5cN.png

Comment: @ZeffryReynando remove this line of code from build method and add inside init method. It will work, the reason it got crashed is, provider has to initialise before building your UI.

final globalProvider = Provider.of<GlobalProvider>(context);

Comment: if i initialize provider inside initState , the value not rebuild. Because if i initialize it inside InitState , i should add listen = false.